# spring Kafka ConsumerFactory bean not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to establish the Kafka consumer using `spring-kaka-2.2.0` and `spring-boot-2.1.0` but I'm having the weird issue saying `ConsumerFactory` bean not found but still it is there in config.

I have two types of messages in topic `Student` and `Professor` I'm trying to consumes them using `@KafkaListener` and `@KafkaHandler` but not gone so far

Here is my config with import statements

```
package com.kafka.configuration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.AckMode;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.BatchMessagingMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.StringJsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Value("${kafka.consumer.bootstrap-server}")
private String bootstrapServer;

@Bean("consumerConfigs")
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-3");
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
            "professor:com.kafka.model.Professor, student:com.kafka.model.Student");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test-3");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
    return props;
}

@Bean("consumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "KafkaAutoConfiguration")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter()));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public StringJsonMessageConverter converter() {
    return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
   }

}
```

**Service**

```
 @Service
 @KafkaListener(topics = "test-events",id = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
 public class KafkaConsumerService {

@KafkaHandler
public void student(List<Student> stu) {
    System.out.println(stu);
}

@KafkaHandler
public void professor(List<Professor> pro) {
    System.out.println(pro);
}

@KafkaHandler
public void listenDefault(List<Object> obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
    }

 }
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' that could not be found.

 The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
  - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' consumerFactory
  - User-defined bean method 'consumerFactory' in 'KafkaConsumerConfig'


 Action:

 Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' in your configuration.
```

---

But if make minor changes removing `@Bean` on `consumerFactory()` method and directly instating is working But still it is not taking properties from `consumerConfigs() Map`. it is trying to map default to `localhost:9092` but I'm trying to connect remote cluster.

```
 factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to override boot's default container factory, you must name it `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` since its condition is on the presence of a bean with that name.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
```

That said, it's not clear why you are wiring up your own consumer and container factories since everything you are doing can be configured in `application.yml` (or `.properties`) and by adding a `@Bean` for the message converter (boot will wire it in for you).

Your `ConsumerFactory` does not have the correct generic types for the Boot autowired factory.

Comment: ya I know sir, but I'm interested to do config my own I believe it will give some info to me, it is working sir but not consuming anything from topic and I can see partitions assigned, any idea sir on this?

Comment: can you please let me know sir what mistake I'm doing, I updated complete code

Comment: I've told you what you are wrong - the factory has the wrong bean name; you should use `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` so that boot doesn't wire its own. Your consumer factory is not compatible with boot's container factory.

Comment: sorry sir I did that change then only it worked, but not polling any data, sorry for incorrect update @Gary Russell

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments - that's why I missed it. It's hard to say; you are setting the initial offset to earliest which will start from the beginning for a new group, but from the current offset for an existing group. If you want to go back to the beginning for a new group you have to perform a seek. If you still can't figure it out; ask a new question, showing configuration and logs.

Comment: sorry sir I'm dumb I will ask new question but first I will try to solve this if not I will ask tomorrow thank you so much sir for help